# LifeCycleListener - is there a way how run code before beforePageLoad event?

Tags: xpages

Is there a way how to run code (LifeCycle event) before  'beforePageLoad' event? ... generaly as an entry point for every requests coming to all xpages? Seems like the LifeCycleListener runs only for some subset of events and this one is missing ... any idea how to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the LifeCycleListener is a standard JSF construct. The Page Load event is separate from the JSF lifecycle, an XPages construct.

The ViewHandler may be the way to go. That has a createView method, which is what creates the component tree. If you're familiar with Jesse Gallagher's XPages Scaffolding project that uses a ViewHandler http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Scaffolding

There's also a ViewHandler in XSP Starter Kit. I can't remember for certain whether the crateView code runs before or after the beforePageLoad, so it might need a bit of trial and error about whether to put your code before or after the super.createView() call.